# Default Display Tabbed Content

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I'm having trouble with the tab set I'm building. While the tabs work when clicked, I can't get a default tab to display. I'd like the first tab to open and visible upon page load.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```js
function openValueImage(evt, valueProp) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablink;

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();


  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }


  tablink = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablink.length; i++) {
    tablink[i].className = tablink[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }


  document.getElementById(valueProp).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}
```

```css
.tab {overflow:hidden;}
.tabcontent {display: none;}
.tab button {cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s; background-color:transparent !important;text-align:left!important; padding-left: 0px; 
padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 20px; opacity:.75;}
.tab button.active {border-top:2px solid #ffb547  !important; opacity:1 !important;}
.tab button:hover {border-top: solid 3px #ffb547 !important; opacity:1 !important;}
```

```html
<div id="content-1" class="tabcontent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt=""></div>

<div id="content-2" class="tabcontent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080" alt=""></div>

<div id="content-3" class="tabcontent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt=""></div>

<div id="content-4" class="tabcontent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080" alt=""></div>

<div>

  <button class="tablink" onclick="openValueImage(event, 'content-1')" id="defaultOpen"> <h3>Make Smarter Decisions</h3>
<p>Organize your loan or security portfolio data and model scenarios so you can confidently manage risk.</p></button>
  
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openValueImage(event, 'content-2')"><h3>Work More Efficiently</h3>
<p>Make complex data analysis simple with our powerful platform and team of experts.</p></button>
  
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openValueImage(event, 'content-3')"><h3>Consult the Experts</h3>
<p>Select data scientists and quants to solve your toughest portfolio data and risk-management problems.</p></button>
  
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openValueImage(event, 'content-4')"><h3>Scale Effortlessly</h3>
<p>Adapt technology and human capital as demands change. Grow faster with a platform and company built to scale.</p></button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: _"the tabs work when clicked"_ - so do basically what you did to make that happen, but specifically for the first tab, and when the document has loaded ...?

Comment: Btw., stuff like this when done, pardon the expression, "amateurishly", generally has terrible usability. So if you place any value in that, you should perhaps go with an established solution provided by a library or framework, like f.e. bootstrap.

Comment: I do appreciate the advice, but I'm working within a WordPress theme, so I don't want to introduce any additional frameworks that may break the theme I'm working in. I'm not a developer, so I know my code may not be the cleanest option, but it will do what I need it to do. Once I find a plugin that does exactly what I want, I'll probably use that instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();`

This line should be outside your `openValueImage` function.

```js
function openValueImage(evt, valueProp) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablink;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }


  tablink = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablink.length; i++) {
    tablink[i].className = tablink[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }


  document.getElementById(valueProp).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.tab {overflow:hidden;}
.tabcontent {display: none;}
.tab button {cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s; background-color:transparent !important;text-align:left!important; padding-left: 0px; 
padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 20px; opacity:.75;}
.tab button.active {border-top:2px solid #ffb547  !important; opacity:1 !important;}
.tab button:hover {border-top: solid 3px #ffb547 !important; opacity:1 !important;}
```

```html
<div id="content-1" class="tabcontent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt=""></div>

<div id="content-2" class="tabcontent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080" alt=""></div>

<div id="content-3" class="tabcontent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt=""></div>

<div id="content-4" class="tabcontent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080" alt=""></div>

<div>

  <button class="tablink" onclick="openValueImage(event, 'content-1')" id="defaultOpen"> <h3>Make Smarter Decisions</h3>
<p>Organize your loan or security portfolio data and model scenarios so you can confidently manage risk.</p></button>
  
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openValueImage(event, 'content-2')"><h3>Work More Efficiently</h3>
<p>Make complex data analysis simple with our powerful platform and team of experts.</p></button>
  
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openValueImage(event, 'content-3')"><h3>Consult the Experts</h3>
<p>Select data scientists and quants to solve your toughest portfolio data and risk-management problems.</p></button>
  
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openValueImage(event, 'content-4')"><h3>Scale Effortlessly</h3>
<p>Adapt technology and human capital as demands change. Grow faster with a platform and company built to scale.</p></button>
  
</div>
```